# Emacs 24 - daemon mode missing -c/-t options?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I'm running the latest beta release of Emacs 24. I can get it to start in daemon mode, however I can't create new consoles or anything. It appears that the -c and -t commands aren't options anymore, even when looking under the help section. Any ideas how to get new frames open with emacsclient?

EDIT

This is for Mac OS X Lion by the way.

Thanks

Comment: I assume a 'not' is missing in your description. However this is
weird, I use the git version and it works.

Did you start a emacs daemon with a particular name ? i.e. `emacs
--daemon="some-name"`, if so, don't forget to use `emacsclient -s
"some-name" -c ...`

Comment: @Daimrod So the version I'm using is from: [http://bandwidth.porkrind.org/emacs-builds/Emacs-pretest-24.0.91-universal-10.6.7.dmg](http://bandwidth.porkrind.org/emacs-builds/Emacs-pretest-24.0.91-universal-10.6.7.dmg)

I'm not starting it up with a particular name or anything. Here are the options i get when doing: emacsclient --help ->

The following OPTIONS are accepted:

-V,
-H,
-e,
-n,
-d,
-s,
-f,
-a,

So no -c or -t options. Not sure why... I just saw a new build in November so I'll try that one and comment if it has the options.

[EDIT] Downloaded the new version. Still no -c/-t

Comment: It's weird, I think you should probably send an email to the author of this build. You can also try to build your own version from CVS (a git and a bzr repo are available).

Comment: So I installed the latest nightly build for Mac and the options still aren't there... I don't get it. Running emacsclient from
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin gives nothing of the sort. Could it be because they seem to be building on 10.6.8 and not on 10.7? Blah... Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was still running the old emacsclient that came preinstalled with Mac OS X as opposed to the new one in Emacs24..